# Declaring a table in an inheritance hierarchy, where the children also references another entry in the base table

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

My problem, simplified and translated to something any programmer can relate to, looks like this:

1. I have an Issue Tickets table. Each entry (ticket) has a type: simple or complex. I use a numerical unique id as PK.

A complex ticket needs additional information compared to a simple ticket, so there's another table just for complex tickets. One of such info must reference a different ticket id. Imagine that this is because a complex ticket is linked to a pre-existing ticket issue from which it depends (always exactly only one and never its own!).

2. The Complex Ticket table uses as PK a FK: the Issue Tickets PK. Since the complex ticket always needs to specify another ticket id (constraints: not its own), I need to use another FK to Issue Tickets as a 'normal' field.

Can I do something of the sort? Is it a bad pattern?

```
CREATE TABLE Issue_Tickets
(
    ticket_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ticket_type CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Complex_Tickets
(
    ticket_id INT NOT NULL,
    father_ticket_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES Issue_Tickets(ticket_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (father_ticket_id) REFERENCES Issue_Tickets(ticket_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
    CONSTRAINT no_self_reference CHECK (ticket_id <> father_ticket_id)
)
```

Comment: Very reasonable definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)